# How to add access token go geneated openapi typescript-angular client

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, swagger, openapi

I´m having following setup...

Backend: Spring boot with openapi code generation for my angular client

Frontend: Angular

I can import the generated code into my project and I can easily use the methods from the generated code. The Problem is I´m not able to authenticate at the backend. In the README.md of the generated code there is following

```
// configuring providers with an authentication service that manages your access tokens
import { ApiModule, Configuration } from '';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ ApiModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    providers: [
      {
        provide: Configuration,
        useFactory: (authService: AuthService) => new Configuration(
          {
            accessToken: authService.getAccessToken.bind(authService)
          }
        ),
        deps: [AuthService],
        multi: false
      }
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

How does the AuthService look like or the getAccessToken function of the Service? If I´m trying to build my own Service which gets the token, the application wont work anymore. There is only a white page and no errors displayed.

How can I implement the token so that it is used by the generated typescript client?